# Complex array in ServiceStack request

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack

I am sending the following request parameters to my service; among which, is the `filter` parameter which is a multidimensional array:

```
filter[0][field]:homeCountry
filter[0][data][type]:string
filter[0][data][value]:united s
page:2
start:200
limit:200
sort:homeCountry
dir:ASC
```

The querystring is encoded like so:

```
paymentratetrip.json?filter%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=homeCountry&filter%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D%5Btype%5D=string&filter%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D%5Bvalue%5D=united%20s&page=2&start=200&limit=200&sort=homeCountry&dir=AS
```

Currently, my C# request object looks like this:

```
public class PaymentRateTripRequest
{    
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public string sort { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
}
```

How can I modify my request object to receive the `filter` parameter which could be a multidimensional array?

Note:  I am using ServiceStack.

The only way I can think is to send the entire request object as a parameter to my method like so:

```
public object Get(PaymentRateTripRequest req)
{
    return _repository.GetAllRates(req.start, req.limit, req.sort, req.dir, this.Request.OriginalRequest);
}
```

But, this doesn't seem like the best solution.

**Edit:** this.Request.QueryString

```
this.Request.QueryString
{filter%5b0%5d%5bfield%5d=homeCountry&filter%5b0%5d%5bdata%5d%5btype%5d=string&filter%5b0%5d%5bdata%5d%5bvalue%5d=united+s&page=2&start=200&limit=200&sort=homeCountry&dir=ASC}
    [System.Web.HttpValueCollection]: {filter%5b0%5d%5bfield%5d=homeCountry&filter%5b0%5d%5bdata%5d%5btype%5d=string&filter%5b0%5d%5bdata%5d%5bvalue%5d=united+s&page=2&start=200&limit=200&sort=homeCountry&dir=ASC}
    base {System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase}: {filter%5b0%5d%5bfield%5d=homeCountry&filter%5b0%5d%5bdata%5d%5btype%5d=string&filter%5b0%5d%5bdata%5d%5bvalue%5d=united+s&page=2&start=200&limit=200&sort=homeCountry&dir=ASC}
    _all: null
    _allKeys: {string[8]}
    AllKeys: {string[8]}
```

**Edit:** `filter` is still empty.

[image]

Comment: But perhaps it is the right and best way to wrap all as a single object.

Comment: I updated my question; any idea how to get these array variables into a usable form?  For instance, a dictionary or object of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative solution that requires no changes to your client and therefore will accept the query string in the format you have currently:

> paymentratetrip.json?filter%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=homeCountry&filter%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D%5Btype%5D=string&filter%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D%5Bvalue%5D=united%20s&page=2&start=200&limit=200&sort=homeCountry&dir=AS

The disadvantage of this method is that it's more code to maintain. The JSV method is simpler.

### Request attribute to populate the filter from the querystring:

We can use a ServiceStack filter to intercept the query string before it reaches the action method. It can then parse the custom filter format and populate the filter object of the DTO.

```cs
public class FilterAttribute : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter
{
    IHasRequestFilter IHasRequestFilter.Copy()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public int Priority { get { return int.MinValue; } }

    FilterField CreateOrUpdateField(ref Dictionary<string, FilterField> filter, string id)
    {
        if(filter.ContainsKey(id))
            return filter[id];

        var field = new FilterField { Data = new Dictionary<string, object>() };
        filter.Add(id, field);

        return field;
    }

    public void RequestFilter(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        var filteredDto = requestDto as IFilter;
        if(filteredDto == null)
            return;

        const string fieldPattern = @"filter\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]\[field\]";
        const string dataPattern = @"filter\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]\[data\]\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]";

        Dictionary<string, FilterField> filter = new Dictionary<string, FilterField>();
        foreach(var property in req.QueryString.AllKeys)
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(property, fieldPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if(match.Success)
            {
                // Field
                var id = match.Groups[1].Value;
                var field = CreateOrUpdateField(ref filter, id);
                field.Field = req.QueryString[property];

            } else {
                match = Regex.Match(property, dataPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if(match.Success)
                {
                    // Data value
                    var id = match.Groups[1].Value;
                    var keyName = match.Groups[2].Value;
                    var field = CreateOrUpdateField(ref filter, id);
                    if(!field.Data.ContainsKey(keyName))
                        field.Data.Add(keyName, req.QueryString[property]);
                }
            }
        }

        filteredDto.Filter = filter.Values.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You will also need to add this interface and `FilterField` class:

```cs
public class FilterField
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,object> Data { get; set; }
}

public interface IFilter
{
    FilterField[] filter { get; set; }
}
```

Then you simply need to update your DTO so it looks like this:

```cs
[Route("/paymentratetrip", "GET"]
[Filter]
public class PaymentRateTripRequest : IFilter
{   
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public string sort { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }

    public FilterField[] filter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; I will try this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a property with the filter to your DTO, such as below:

```cs
public class PaymentRateTripRequest
{   
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public string sort { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }

    public FilterField[] filter { get; set; }
}

public class FilterField
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,object> data { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you to add any number of fields to filter by, and by making the `data` property of the `FilterField` a `Dictionary<string, object>` you can add as many data properties as needed.

Then you can populate the `filter` parameter in your `PaymentRateTripRequest` using JSV format. You can learn about [JSV format here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Json-jsv-and-xml#wiki-jsv-text-format-json--csv). JSV Format (i.e. JSON-like Separated Values) is a JSON inspired format that uses CSV-style escaping for the least overhead and optimal performance.

> paymentratetrip.json?filter=[{field:homeCountry,data:{type:string,value:"united s"}},{field:other,data:{type:int,value:34,special:true}}]&page=2&start=200&limit=200&sort=homeCountry&dir=ASC

Then you can access the filter as a regular property on your request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this require that I change my request to use JSV?  I don't think I can change the request querystring; only the service layer.  I updated my question with an image that shows my `filter` variable is still null.  How can I get `filter` to populate from the querystring?

Comment: @user1477388 Yes you would have to send JSV format for the `filter` property of the query string. The rest of the request would remain in the same format. What kind of client are you using? Why can't you change the format of the filter query string? There is another way to tackle the problem, but it far from easy, it then requires parsing over the filter property, JSV is *the* ServiceStack way to do it.

Comment: The client side is ExtJS.  When I google ExtJS + JSV nothing even comes up!  I am not sure if it's possible.

Comment: @user1477388 You won't find many articles on it's use, JSV was created by the creator of ServiceStack. If you set the value of the filter property to `[{field:homeCountry,data:{type:string,value:"united s"}},{field:other,data:{type:int,value:34,special:true}}]` it will populate, given you have added the `FilterField[] filter` to your DTO. It's possible because I have it working.

Comment: You're right, I see it working, too.  The thing is, I just don't know how to change my clientside to send JSV instead of JSON...

Comment: Let me ask you this - would it be easier if I could send these variables via POST instead of GET?  I think I can make ExtJS send via POST and not GET.

Comment: @user1477388 Absolutely. If you send using post then you can set the value of `filter` using JSON. I will also add an alternative solution that will require no changes to your client.